# Sql matching one value against multiple columns

Tags: php, sql

On my website I have a search box. At the moment it works, but it only will search the body of the text for keywords. To do that I'm using sql's match against function.

```
public function searchKey(){
 $key = $this->uri->segment(3); 
 $search = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM story_tbl WHERE MATCH (body) AGAINST ("'.$key.'");');
 return $search->result();
}
```

I would like it if I could not only search through the body, but also the title and the description as well. Is there any way to do this?

I've already tried putting comma's where I'm calling the body, like this (body, title, descr) but it just spits me back a sql error. and I do have full text enabled.

Comment: A comma-separated list of columns is correct, what SQL error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting back a syntax error message, thus why I thought I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just add all the columns you want to search within the `MATCH` clause

```
... MATCH (body,title,description) AGAINST ...
```

Comment: @zazvorniki What SQL error do you get? That is the correct syntax.

Comment: @zazvorniki What is the specific message?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(body, title) AGAINST ("window")' at line 1